# Offline Message using smack in android

Tags: android

I can able to create small chat application using smack api.how ever ,i am unable to receive offline messages by using **offlineMessageManager** class in smack api.It just throws a **nullpointerexception** when i supposed to call method getMessageCount in the first line of code that i pasted here.

```
            DiscoverInfo info = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection).discoverInfo(null,namespace);
            Form extendedInfo = Form.getFormFrom(info);
            if (extendedInfo != null) {
                String value = extendedInfo.getField("number_of_messages").getValues().next();
                return Integer.parseInt(value);
            }
            }

            return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same issue you described.

I got the ASmack project source, and I'm generating my own library.

The fix for this particular issue is to call

ServiceDiscoveryManager manager = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);

after you logged in. Seems they missed to initialize this class at some point.

Let me know if you have other issues after this, I got a ClassCastException, but I can help you if you got it.

-f4

Comment: hi, I am getting the same issue, you faced, can you help me how to solve it, cos dont know when to initialize this manager after login or before>. I will be happy if got your help.

Comment: You just need to put the line

ServiceDiscoveryManager manager = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);

Right after you invoke "login" method.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, but i already did this before, just after login but its saying in logcat that "feature-not-implemented(501)", dont know about this. do you?. I am using asmack-issue15.jar

Comment: No clue :(, but I'm using ASmack Git repository to get their source code https://github.com/rtreffer/asmack

Comment: @fr4gus a year and a bit later.... I am getting the classcast exception...Any help?